# How do I append html elements with varying id tags and text into my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current page looks like this WITHOUT the input box. The problem I'm having is with the input. I'm going to have multiple controls with the same **id** name, and I want the **value** to be different for each row. What should I do to automate this? If I hardcoded it, I would still get the same ID tag on each loop iteration. My goal is to be able to add and delete entire target groups at the end

```
Target Name: text <--- what it looks like now
Command Line: [ input box ] <----- desired output
Build Env: [ input box ]
Rel Out: [ input box ]
Rel Log: [ input box ]
Dep: [ input box ]
```

my JS looks like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Target Name: " + records[i].TargetName));
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Command Line: " + records[i].CommandLine));
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Build Environment: " + records[i].BuildEnvTypeName));
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Relative Output Path: " + records[i].RelativeOutputPath));
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Relative Log Path: " + records[i].RelativeLogPath));
    row.append($('<tr></tr>').text("Dependencies: " + records[i].Dependencies));
    $('#AddTargetTable').append(row);
}
```

the input box part I want to append for each part (this is specific for the target name one):

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="target-name" value="<% =TargetName %>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **You cannot have multiple HTML elements with the same id on the same page**. That's what classes are for.

Comment: Id should be keep unique, you can give them different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass a unique identifier along with your record data you can add that identifier to each row. You don't need element ID's for tasks like this.

```
/* add identifier to start of row */
var row = $('<tr data-id="'+records[i].id +'"></tr>');
```

Then when you interact with a row you can pull the `data-id` using `jQuery.data()` method.

As for the `input`'s you need to use `html()` instead of `text()` for cell data.

A simple template function will help keep the clutter down

```
function inputTemplate( value, type){
  return ' <div class="control-group">'+
              '<div class="controls">'+
                    '<input type="text" value="'+value+'" data-type="'+type+'" />'+
              '</div>'+
           '</div>';
}
```

Adding cells:

```
row.append($('<td>').html("Command Line: " + inputTemplate( records[i].CommandLine, 'Command')));
```

Now add a change handler for the input's. Will use similar row traversal approach for delete row.

```
$('.controls input').change(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    var newValue=$(this).val();
    var fieldType= $(this).data('type')
    alert('new value for  '+ fieldType +' in row ' + rowId +' is ' + newValue );
    updateServer( rowId, fieldType, newValue);
})
```